# Google Coral performance isn't amazing

Tags: performance, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

I have been benchmarking the two coral devices I have [USB and one channel to a Dual Edge TPU M.2], for deploying a reinforcement learning agent. For my particular workload, so far the results have been quite disappointing. In essence, the Coral is usually *much* slower than the CPU.

Benchmarked NNs:

- Large = 4 Hidden Layers, 512 wide
- Medium = 4 Hidden Layers, 256 wide
- Small = 1 Hidden Layer, 256 wide
- Huge = 8 Hidden Layers, 1024 Wide
- Max Wide = 2 Hidden Layers, 2700 Wide
- Inch Wide Mile Deep = 256 Hidden Layers, 64 Wide

I'm generating the NNs, and converting them to Edge-friendly TFLite, using this: https://github.com/chunky/sb3_to_coral/ [train using stable-baselines 3, convert to edge]. In each case, the input and output layers are still float32, but everything in between runs on the TPU [according to the TPU compiler]. For my particular gym and benchmark the input tensor is 206 values.

The "Pi" is a Pi4 8GB. The "Desktop" is an intel i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz with a GeForce GTX 1050 Ti.

The first chart is for large/medium/small NNs; those NNs typify agents that behave well in my Gym. Y axis is ms/inference, lower is better:
[image: Benchmark the first]

Some observations:

- The Pi CPU outperforms the USB coral on my desktop. That's a surprise.
- The Pi breaks even on the larger NN [so is worth doing because the CPU is free'd up, for no loss of performance], but outperforms the Coral on the smaller networks
- USB appears to be a poor deal. On both systems, I have the coral plugged into the blue port. During the benchmark, the coral is visibly constantly blinking
- The PCIe flavor seems good, unfortunately the Pi 4 doesn't have a M.2 slot

The second chart is for larger networks; both "huge" and "max wide" are designed to almost-fill the space on the device. "inch wide mile deep" doesn't come close, but was an attempt to explore whether narrow networks somehow benefit from the Coral's internal architecture.

[image: Benchmark, the second]

The code that does the inference itself [ignoring the harness that calls it]:

```py
class TFLiteDream:
    def __init__(self, dreamenv, checkpoint):
        self.dreamenv = dreamenv

        if 'edgetpu' in checkpoint:
            from pycoral.utils import edgetpu
            edge_tpus_available = edgetpu.list_edge_tpus()
            dev = os.getenv("EDGETPU_DEVICE", ":0")
            print("Coral TPUs available: {}, using {}".format(edge_tpus_available, dev))
            self.interpreter = edgetpu.make_interpreter(checkpoint, device=dev)
        else:
            self.interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path=checkpoint)
        self.interpreter.allocate_tensors()
        self.input_details = self.interpreter.get_input_details()
        self.output_details = self.interpreter.get_output_details()

    def get_single_action(self, obs):
        input_data = np.float32(obs.reshape(1, -1))
        self.interpreter.set_tensor(self.input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
        self.interpreter.invoke()
        output_data = self.interpreter.get_tensor(self.output_details[0]['index'])
        return output_data
```

So, what's going on? This thing is supposed to be fast, but it's not doing that great for me. I also observe that it's not even warm to the touch, even when I install the "-max" package that warns me I'll burn my fingers.

Are my networks just ones that won't perform on it, for some reason? Am I doing something wrong with how I feed it? Is USB just that bad? Am I missing something else?

Comment: Hi, I do not know what is your model but I have similar issue for basic MLP model. A issue confirms that the coral works well with convolution model only. It is bit weird because from my knowledge convolutions are transformed into matrix multiplication.  https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/issues/89